# how can a php generated image have a .png extension?

Tags: php, png, generated

I am the owner of a minecraft server and got fed up with sites that generate png banners with live contents (getting that content by plugins i must install).

So I tried to make mine :)

all fine and well the image is generated and displayed fine and perfectly using basicly this:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/live.png");
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($im, 4, 104, 38, $numOnlineListTotal.'/'.$MaxCapacity, $black);
imagestring($im, 4, 325, 38, $numAdmnMod, $black);
imagestring($im, 4, 104, 57, $MCVersion, $black);
imagestring($im, 4, 325, 57, $BukkitBuild, $black);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The problem is when i try to enter the link to my php file that generates the image to a site like lets say minecraftforums.net, it says this type of image in invalid for use with their forums, and i can understand this since what i enter as the link is :
http://mcaddictgallery.info/shared/live.php
not a .png ending file

how could i have the link end in .png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Mod Rewrite. Assuming that your server has the mod_rewrite plugin installed, you can put the following in a .htaccess file in the same directory as the image script.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^live.png$ live.php
```

The easiest way to know if it's enabled/installed is if the server returns a `500` error when trying to load anything in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL rewriting.  For Apache, this will be something like mod_rewrite.  There are other solutions for other serving platforms.